# Removing Duplicates from a Sorted Array

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures

I came across below interview question and its solution and I am having hard time figuring out on how it is working:

> Given a sorted array nums, remove the duplicates in-place such that
>   each element appear only once and return the new length. Do not
>   allocate extra space for another array, you must do this by modifying
>   the input array in-place with O(1) extra memory.

Below is the solution. Can someone explain me on how this is working? I am not able to understand the below algorithm and also if I uncomment system.out line then it throws exception so how come `nums[i - 1]` works in if block for the case where `i=0`?

```
  public static int removeDuplicatess(int[] nums) {
    int i = 0;
    for (int n : nums) {
      // System.out.println(nums[i - 1]);
      if (i == 0 || n > nums[i - 1])
        nums[i++] = n;
    }
    return i;
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This method iterates over every number in the `Array`. It starts by adding the first number in the `Array`, since it cannot possibly be a duplicate as it is the first number. (Which is what the `i == 0` part of the `if` is for. Then it looks at one index back to see if `n > nums[i - 1]`. The only way this will be true is if `n` is not a duplicate, as the list is sorted. If this is the case then we add it to the `Array`. Take this example:

```
[0, 1, 1, 3]
```

On the first iteration:

- `n == 0`
- `i == 0`
- `i == 0` evaluates to true. `0` is added to index `0`.

Second iteration:

- `n == 1`
- `i == 1`
- `n > nums[i - 1]` (1 >`0`) evaluates to true, `1` is added to the `Array`

Third Iteration:

- `n == 1`
- `i == 2`
- `n > nums[i - 1]` (1 > 1) evaluates to `false` so `1` is *not* added to the `Array`

Fourth iteration:

- `n == 3`
- `i == 2`
- `n > nums[i - 1]` (3 > 1) evaluates to `true` and `3` is added to the `Array`.

---

> Also if I uncomment system.out line then it throws exception so how come nums[i - 1] works in if block for the case where i=0?

This is because `||` is a short circuiting operation. Which means that if one side evaluates to true, the other side will not be evaluated. So in the case where `i == 0`:

```
if (i == 0 || n > nums[i - 1])
    ^^^^^^--- Evaluates to true. num[i-1] is not considered
    nums[i++] = n;
```

Then you call `nums[i++]`, (which increments `i` after it places `n` in `nums[i]`), which will make `i` 1. Then you will call `num[i -1]`, which will be `0`, a valid index.

Answer (score 1):

You iterate all numbers in the array. Since the array is already sorted, every loop-variable n will be bigger or equal to the last one.

The first number (case `i==0`) always goes into the result (Since a single number cannot be duplicate).

After that just check if the currently observed number is bigger than the last one we decided to keep (if it was less your array wasn't sorted and your algorithm breaks; if it is equal it is a duplicate) and write it to the array at the i+1'th spot.

Answer (score 1):

`nums[i - 1]` works due to the short evaluation of complex logical expressions - when the first term `i == 0` is true, there is no need to evaluate the second term (in case of logical `OR` operation between terms).

And logic of algorithm is staightforward - if current value is the same as previous - omit it, otherwise write it into squeezed initial part of array.